# SwiftUI: Property type does not match wrappedValue for type FetchedResults<NSManagedObject>

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to implement this solution: [Combine, Publishers, and Core Data](https://betterprogramming.pub/combine-publishers-and-core-data-424b68fe9473) but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Here is my implantation:

```
class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var customers: [Task] = []
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        CDPublisher(request: Task.fetchRequest(),
                    context: viewContext)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                  receiveValue: { value in
                   print("value: \(value)")
                })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

This is part of my view implementation:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    var dataModel: DataModel
    var task: FetchedResults<Task>
    init() {
        self.dataModel = DataModel(viewContext: viewContext)
    }
    var body: some View {
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error or what do I need to do to fix this error?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Your `@FetchedRequest` should be of type FetchedResults<Result> Result should be whatever your entity name is from your Core Data model. Don't get it confused for the attribute but the entity name. It can look like

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
var dataModel: FetchedResults<Results>
```

Comment: That worked. But still I'm getting this error `Cannot assign to property: 'dataModel' is a get-only property`. Do you know how can I fixed?

Comment: @user2924482 it looks like you want to have access to your class DataModel. You can gain access with `@StateObject var data = DataModel()`. You don't need to init() the dataModel.

Comment: That doesn't work because I need to pass the `NSManagedObjectContext ` .`init(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the data model, `@FetchRequest` does it all for you.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(tasks) { task in
            TaskView(task: task)
        }
```